# Rails enum integrated with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, enums

I have a `User` model, which will have `designation` as attribute.

I have created a `Enum` in `Postgres` and made `designation` as `enum`.

Here is migration file.

```
class AddDesignationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  execute <<-SQL
   CREATE TYPE user_designations AS ENUM ('Newbie', 'Coder', 'Owner', 'Lead', 'Architect');
  SQL

  add_column :users, :designation, :user_designations
 end
end
```

I have also designation as enum in model file `User.rb`

```
enum designation: { newbie: 'Newbie' , coder: 'Coder', owner: 'Owner',
                  lead: 'Lead', architect: 'Architect' }
```

Now when I am trying to get designation of a User, by say `User.first.designation`. I am getting value `coder` instead of `Coder`.

But when I just type `User.first` in console, I can see the value of designation as `Coder`, which is expected. But I don't why it is getting messed up while extracting it using `User.first.designation`.

Please hep me where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: *" it is getting messed up while extracting it using User.first.designation"* What do you mean, **"messed up"**? What are you expecting to see? What are you seeing instead?

Comment: "Now when I am trying to get designation of a User, by say User.first.designation. I am getting value coder instead of Coder."

Comment: Expecting Coder with CAPITAL 'C' instead of small

Comment: An obvious guess is that this is because you defined the mapping: `coder: 'Coder'`, instead of `Coder: 'Coder'`. However, I'm a little confused why you are defining an enum of strings, rather than the standard enum of integers -- i.e. `enum designation: %w(newbie coder owner lead architect)`, so each value is actually stored as an integer in the database.

Comment: `User.first[:designation]`  - What does this return to you ?

Comment: @dkp that worked!! :)

Comment: @OldMonk great & I will extend it as an answer.

Comment: @TomLord Some designation will be with space, such as 'Tech Architect'. These values can be put in postgres enum, but won't if using vanilla enum using rails

Comment: @OldMonk I'm sure you are not using Rails 5, what is your Rails version ?

Comment: @dkp Yes I am using 4.2. Is it resolved in Rails 5??

Comment: @OldMonk yes, it should work in Rails 5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with Rails 4 and this has been fixed in [**Rails 5** as per this patch](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c51f9b61ce1e167f5f58f07441adcfa117694301).

You can anyway do this to get the enum value in Rails 4:

```
User.first[:designation]
```